# A free site for uploading files for basic HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, storage

I have tried to store my files and then use their links through dropbox but it doesnt work on mobile(I dont know why).So when im out showing my "creations" to friends I cant because the images cant load.So please help.

Thanks!

Sorry I wasnt clear enough.I need it just to upload images so i can:
  <   img src="[Link]">

Comment: You have not provided us with any code to look at, or any link to your sites to see what is the problem. How can we help you if you don't show us the bad code?

Comment: Give [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/) a try.

Answer (score 1):

If your website is just some static files, you can use github to post your work.

[Read this link](https://pages.github.com/) for step by step guide.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just a storage to your files in the cloud.I recommend to upload your files to **cloud storage** like **google drive**, **dropbox**, and **mediafire**. Or join **behance**, **dribble**, **pexels**, If it's image you can also use some social networking site to post your image such as **flickr**, **facebook**, and  **twitter**. I hope this help.